# Object Error in Outlook Function

Tags: vba, outlook, compiler-errors

I am writing a function that prints out the folder name in the debug window. For some reason when I call this function I get an object required error. I have set the object so I am unsure what is wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    function email_function(fldr as outlook.folder)
         debug.print fldr
    end function



    Sub email()

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNspace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set start_fldr = objNspace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


    Debug.Print start_fldr

    If Not start_fldr Is Nothing Then
       email_function (start_fldr)
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong syntax.

```
Call email_function(fldr)

'or

email_function fldr
```

Original code in Question:

```
Sub email()
    Dim objOutlook As Application
    Dim objnSpace As Namespace
    Dim start_fldr As folder
    Dim fldr As folder

    Set objOutlook = Application
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set start_fldr = objnSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Set fldr = start_fldr.Folders.GetFirst

    Call email_function(fldr)

    email_function fldr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I knew it was something simple i as missing.